# how do I crop a String without copying it

Tags: ruby

I would like to cut a number of characters from the beginning of a very large String. To save me some memory and time, I would like to avoid making a copy of it, but simply let the string begin at that later index, like it would easily be possible in C by just incrementing the pointer to the string (array).

Is that possible?

Comment: What operations do you want to perform on the string after trimming it?

Comment: I parse a CSV with FasterCSV, catch MalformedCSVErrors and reparse the CSV from the line after the malformed one. Therefore i need to cut the beginning of the CSV. I know, that I could also stream-parse the CSV from the original file, but our architecture doesn't allow this (yet).

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Of course: https://gist.github.com/952883

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't play the "increment the string pointer" trick, but try this:

```
str = 'I would like to cut a number of characters from the beginning of a very large String'
str[0, 10] = ''
str # => "ke to cut a number of characters from the beginning of a very large String"
```

It's the simplest way I know to chop off part of a string in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not possible to do what you would like because of the way Ruby represents strings.

As you mentioned, in C you could simply increment the pointer to the string by some number of characters.  However, in Ruby the String class is implemented by `struct RString` which has a `ptr` field for the underlying C string.  It wouldn't make sense for Ruby to provide a method which increments the ptr field because it would lose track of the original location and would complicate deallocation of that memory.  You might be able to write your own native extension to the String class which does what you want but there are likely additional complications (e.g. regarding hashing).

Comment: Actually, it's possible and `lstrip!` is implemented [this way](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.src/M001197.html). (Not being C specialist, can't tell how deallocation is done)

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not a problem and you need to get rid of the copy operation why not to build your own String class implemented as array:

```
class StringAsArray
    def initialize(s)
        @arr = s.split(//)
    end

    // .... your methods goes here ....

end
```

It should be easy to create methods for cutting etc. Its very naive approach and maybe wont fit for you. Depends on what you need to do.

Comment: _"If memory is not a problem"_ weren't we trying to save memory in first place? (And it's not like this solution saves any time either)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub!` if you know the portion to strip.

```
s = 'cut this string'
s.gsub!('cut ', '')
s
# => "cut this string"
```

or you can use `slice!`

```
s.slice!(s.index('this')..-1)
s
# => "cut this string"
```

Comment: Are you sure this avoids copying the string?

Comment: The `bang!` version modifies the string in place without creating a copy.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak I answered the question. If you use the bang! version, the string is modified in place without allocating a new instance.

Comment: The object_id remains the same. But doesn't that mean, that the content is copied to the beginning of the allocated memory? Or does the object_id not represent an address in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure that String#reverse! doesn't copy internally, but this is the method I've used in the past:

```
mystring.reverse!
num_of_chars.times {mystring.chop!}
mystring.reverse!
```

Although now that I look at it I think the Tin Man has a more elegant solution.